# How to have two users with ssh access

Tags: centos, ssh, users

How can I have access for two users via `ssh`.

Example:

I have two users (not root), `user1` and `user2`. How can I access these two users by SSH. 
I don't want to login to one and switch to other like `su - user1` from uaser2.

I need this, so that user1 and user2 can have their own user and do not disturb other user.

So that setup will allow me to do:
`ssh user1@ip_address`
`ssh user2@ip_address`

Comment: `ssh user1@yourhost` and `ssh user2@yourhost`?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to do?

Comment: Are you after two people logging in to the same user account? Or two people with separate user accounts? Or something else?

Comment: `su user1` and `su user2` ?

Comment: @Puckwang -- from question "I don't want to login to one and switch to other"

Comment: To simplify, I need two users with  ssh access. Like I have user1 and user2 so that I can do `ssh user1@ip` or `ssh user2@ip`. Thanks

Comment: For password authentification, no specific set up is needed, just enter the adequate password. For key authentification you add your own SSH key to the `authorized_keys` files of both users .

Comment: What exactly avoid you to simply create user1 and user2 as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the host you want the users to access, define the users with `useradd user1` and `useradd user2`. If you want to make sure **only** specified users can access over ssh, the easiest way is to set up *public key authentication* (google it) (and disable `password authentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and put the public keys of the respective users in `/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This achieves high security and no access for any users who have no `authorized_keys` file configured.

HTH, cheers,

ppenguin

Comment: Ask for clarification in the comments of the question, not as an answer.

Comment: No, its not how I access from remote. I want help to create two users with SSH access.

Comment: Ok, completely changed answer based on new understanding. This appears to match OP's objective?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson:  Actually, answers of the form ‘‘If you want to do ***foo**,* then the answer is ***bar**.*’’ *are* considered to be acceptable answers.  Note that ppenguin doesn’t have the privilege to post comments yet.